# Firefox "Style-Document could not be loaded" with bower ressources

Tags: gulp, developer-tools, source-maps, firefox-developer-tools

I'm developing Frontend-Applications with Firefox (latest Version 41.0.1.), but had this problem earlier as well.

Im processing *.sass Files with Gulp-Sass, Sourcemap-Support, and something else.

Here the Styles-Task:

```
var paths = {
  folders : {
    css:        'public/assets/css',
    sass:       'public/src/sass'
  },
  files : {
    css:        'public/assets/css/**/*.css',
    sass:       'public/src/sass/**/*.sass'
  }
};

gulp.task('styles', function () {

if(compileOnly != false) {
  var srcFile = compileOnly;
} else {
  var srcFile = paths.files.sass;
}

var processors = [
  autoprefixer({
    browsers: ["last 2 versions", "> 1%", "ie 8"],
    map: true
  }),
  nano({
    safe: true // Disables Z-Index remanufacturing
  }),
  pxtorem({
    replace: false,
    prop_white_list: ['padding', 'margin', 'width', 'height', 'min-width', 'min-height', 'max-width', 'max-height', 'font', 'font-size', 'line-height', 'letter-spacing', 'top', 'left', 'bottom', 'right'],
    selector_black_list: ['body', 'html']
  }),
  postcssrgba({
    properties: [ "background-color", "background", "color", "border", "border-color", "outline", "outline-color", "box-shadow", "text-shadow" ]
  })
]

return gulp.src([srcFile],{base: paths.folders.sass})
  .pipe( plumber( { errorHandler: onError } ) )
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sass({sourcemap: true, style: 'compact'}))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))             // Source Map Generation
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.folders.css))                  // Output
  .pipe(notify({ message: 'Styles task complete' }));
});
```

Everything works fine, sourcemaps are beeing generated, and the firefox developer-tools are showing the correct sources: http://jmp.sh/NfErzKf

But when i click on one of these ressources, i only get this error:

"Style-Document could not be loaded. http://****/assets/bower/uikit/scss/core/nav.scss" (Free translation, since my System-Language is german)

The File is there and has no restrictions.

When i test with a fresh sass-file with no-dependencies and includes, everything is ok. 
Chrome has no problems at all.
Only Firefox, when i include bower-dependencies. 
Could it be the mix of Sass- and Scss-Files?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research and trial & error I could track it down a bit.

So first of all, the error only occurs if there is an inclusion from bower (or probably any other folder on that level). If I comment out all @imports from there all is okay.

**Solution:**
Since the Firefox support of sourceRoot in sourcemaps is a bit buggy ([same issue in browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/681)), I recomend to remove it, because gulp-sourcemaps adds it per default.

You can remove it in the sourcemap by passing null to this option:

```
.pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.', {
    sourceRoot: null
}))
```

Comment: Sincerely, I can't get your solution to work correctly.
The Source-Roots are still not correct.
But i got a workaround, to get them to be correct:
I just put the Map-File in a Sub-Folder:

`.pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))`

Now the sources are loaded correctly, but now i got wrong line-numbers thanks to postcss...